# How Throughput is calculate and display in Sec,Minute and Hours in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, throughput

I have one observation and want to get knowledge on **Throughput calculation**,Some time Throughput is displaying in seconds,some times in minutes and some times in Hours,please any one provide exact answer to calculate throughput and when it will display in **Seconds,Minutes and Hours** in **Jmeter Summary Report**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From JMeter Docs:

> **Throughput** is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is
>   calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last
>   sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed
>   to represent the load on the server. The formula is: Throughput =
>   (number of requests) / (total time).

unit time varies based on the throughput values.

examples:

1. In 10 seconds, 10 requests are sent, then throughput is 10/10 = 1/sec
2. In 10 seconds, 1 requests are sent, then throughput is 1/10 = 0.1/sec = 6/min (showing 0.1/sec in decimals will be automatically shown in next higher unit time)

If you understand, it is to avoid small values (like, 0.1, 0.001 etc). In such cases, higher unit time is more friendly in understanding, while all unit times are correct. It is a matter of usability.

so,

> 1/sec = 60/min = 3600/hour = SAME

Comment: Thank you for answer,now i understand why values are converted into minutes and hours but you said avoid small values like (0.1 and 0.001 sec to minutes) but when it will convert to hours exactly.

Comment: From my knowledge, There is no fixed value which converts the value from unit to unit. It is just readability sake. But, If throughput is in hours unit, it means that requests sent in a hour, are very low. (`n` requests are sent in one hour for `n/hour` throughput value). Understand the concept of Throughput, then you won't get confused by the unit of time.