# Whenever i ran the Jmeter test for less than 10 Thread Groups then all the time "Throughput" shows numbers in "Minutes"

Tags: jmeter, throughput

When I execute test in `JMeter` for less than `10 Thread Groups`, in `Summary Report` column `Throughput` showing result in `Minutes`.

[image]

Can anyone please help me

Comment: please refer my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41934033/2575259, which is similar to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [RateRenderer class source](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/src/jorphan/org/apache/jorphan/gui/RateRenderer.java)

```
String unit = "sec";

if (rate < 1.0) {
    rate *= 60.0;
    unit = "min";
}
if (rate < 1.0) {
    rate *= 60.0;
    unit = "hour";
}
setText(formatter.format(rate) + "/" + unit);
```

So:

- If throughput is more than 1 - time unit is "seconds"
- If your throughput is less than 1 - it's being multiplied by 60 and time unit is set to "minutes"
- If after throughput converting to "minutes" it is still less than 1 - it is being multiplied by 60 and time unit is set to "hours"

If you need to get the throughput in hits per second from minutes - just divide the value by 60.

Other options are:

- Patch the RateRenderer class and comment out the two above "if" clauses
- Use an external 3rd-party tool like [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) for JMeter results analysis